# I want to change the url of img on hover in wordpress

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to change the URL of my image on hover from `/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/loyalty-grey.png` to `/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/loyalty.png`.This is a wordpress website. I have to apply this on more than 100 pages.

I need a solution which can work on all pages with a single code

I have been doing like this but this can't be done for 100 pages.
[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7tPK.png)

Comment: Please specify in details .

Comment: Do you want to update "03" in URL to "04" ?

Comment: no i want to completely change the url.

Comment: From wp_post table you can update that